# How to hide file extension using .htaccess + Restricting access

Tags: .htaccess, web

Guys how to remove a file extension using .htaccess.
example :
file name was "/home.php"

of course after using .htaccess

it can now access using link "/home"

it is possibly to redirect using into 404 error if they visit "/home.php" instead of "/home"

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `Multiviews`:

```
Options +Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

This redirects `/home.php` to `/home`, but you can replace the `301` in the square brackets with `404` if you insist on returning a "not found".

Comment: I put 404 in [L,R=404] but its shows error:    500 Internal Server Error when trying to use ErrorDocument to handle request

Comment: @LuisEdwardMiranda Don't think you can't use errordocument 404 with R=404.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will rewrite `*.php` to `*`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rewrite rule in your `.htaccess` to remove the `php` extension

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Regards,

Source: http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/